# Help parsing one element for another via Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a variable to the button below that I would like to replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var btn = window.document.getElementById('btn_fb_1');
</script>
<button id="btn_fb_1" type="button">Log into Somewhere<br />(Joe Doe)</button>
```

Using the "btn" variable above, how to I replace the entire element with just text like this (notice I need to keep "Joe Doe":

```
Connected to Somewhere<br />(Joe Doe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
var btn = window.document.getElementById('btn_fb_1');
var d = document.createElement('div');
var name = btn.innerHTML.match(/\(.*\)/);
d.innerHTML = 'Connected to Somewhere<br />'+name;
btn.parentNode.replaceChild(d, btn); // replace btn with d
```

Comment: "Joe Doe" is dynamic though. How do I variablize this

Answer (score 1):

If the button is wrapped in an object, change the innerHTML of the parent:

```
<span><button id="btn_fb_1" type="button">Log into Somewhere<br />(Joe Doe)</button></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var regEx = /\(([^)]*)\)/
  var btn = window.document.getElementById('btn_fb_1');
  btn.parentNode.innerHTML=btn.innerHTML.match(regEx)[1]; // extract joe doe (no error checking)
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for the help.. how to I extra "Joe Doe" so I can put it where the x's are: "Connected to Somewhere<br />(xxxxx)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553222/regex-pattern-to-return-text-from-within-brackets

Comment: See my amended answer for example with regular expression from link above

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript frameworks make this a lot easier to do, but this should work.

```
btn.innerHTML = "Connected to Somewhere<br />(Joe Doe)";
```

Comment: That would set the button's innerHTML to what it was to begin with